# url mapping in express w nodejs

Tags: node.js, express

here is my mapping :

```
app.get('/v2/match/:wid/:fid/z/:zid',
    match.whatCampaignMatchThisWebsiteThisFormatThisZone);

app.get('/v2/match/:wid/:fid/o/:oid',
    match.whatCampaignMatchThisWebsiteThisFormatThisOs);
```

The first one work perfectly,
but the second one tell me that the url is not found.

```
Cannot GET /v2/match/widV1H9xiVrb/300x250/o/OM/
```

Any idea why ?

thanks

Comment: Code looks fine..Are you sure you are calling it right? Can you show your client?

Comment: Is the `whatCampaignMatchThisWebsiteThisFormatThisOs` method generating a 404 when it can't find a campaign?